# htaccess rewriterule for profile.php query

Tags: apache, .htaccess, centos

I am trying to write a `.htaccess` `RewriteRule` for a profile page. I want the rule to query a SQL database for a user profile and if that data returns a result to load the `profile.php` page. Example:

- `www.example.com/username`
- or `www.example.com/user.name`
- or `www.example.com/user.name123` and the like...

However, I have other pages like `/login`, `/registration`, `/`, `/chat`, and so on. Every time I try something I keep running into an issue.

I have tried the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(login)$ login.php [QSA]
RewriteRule ^(logout)$ logout.php [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ profile.php?pid=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I am trying to learn as much as I can but I am not comprehending the regex syntax and the conditions. The above rules let me use all the previous pages but it will catch everything else in the `profile.php` page. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: i don't get you, are you trying to execute SQL in htaccess? or you want to allow an sql query on that page?

Comment: @Nix, thank you for responding. I am sorry if I didn't explain it clearly. So, what I want to do is have the profile name ('username', 'user.name', and etc) to execute a query. If the query has a 0 return to display a 404 page, unless the page does exsist. Example: (login points to login.php, but sunshine points to nothing, and robert.sexton should show me.). I don't communicate well so, if I don't explain it well I will try my best.

Comment: You are missing RewriteCond here, why don't you achieve this via your php code? at the top of your page you can execute query, and if result is empty you can echo your 404 and exit further processing

Comment: @Nix, I was thinking the same thing after your question. I figured I could use the query and if it returns 0 I can have the PHP header redirect. The rule RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ profile.php?pid=$1 [L,QSA] actually works but it doesn't get all characters. I can only get the all in one word to work nothing like user.name, user.name123, and etc. I am looking here:  https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html and https://www.hostwinds.com/guide/defining-regex-characters-htaccess/

Comment: @Nix, I think I got it. Could you verify? I am using this: RewriteRule ^([\w-.*]+)/?$ profile.php?pid=$1 [L,QSA]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try following regex, I hope it will solve your problem.

```
^([\w]+|[\w-]+\.+[\w]+)$
```

you can always use this [link](https://regex101.com/r/yMiWBU/1) to test your regex.

Comment: Although this will also catch requests for `profile.php` itself (which "looks like" a `/user.name`) and rewrite to itself, resulting in `profile.php?pid=profile.php&pid=username` - the second `pid` essentially overwrites the first `pid`, so it appears to work as required. But also, unless MultiViews is enabled then `/login` and `/logout` etc. will also be rewritten to `profile.php` since the `L` flag is missing from the earlier directives. But if MultiViews is enabled then the directives to append the file extensions are essentially being ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Try This in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ profile.php?pid=$1
```

make sure that in profile.php you have put certain condition to match the parameters and if not matches it shows error message or redirect you to 404 page
that would be nice

Comment: Parth, thank you for the response. I gave your solution a shot, but, it just gave me my default 404 page. the profile page does have an echo $_GET['pid'] to make sure it gets the variable but it didn't work. Thank you for the help!

Comment: RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ profile.php?pid=$1 [L,QSA] - This rule seems to be kind of on the point I am looking for but it's not catching all characters. it works on username but it doesn't work on user.name or user.name123 and etc. I think I could use this and do the query and if it doesn't exist use the PHP header to redirect to a 404 page?